# Adobe AIR detect if Running in ADL?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I need to detect if running in ADL or not, I can't seem to fine an answer that is guaranteed...I found a couple posts online that say "this might work..." Is there a reliable way to check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding,

```
if (Capabilities.isDebugger)
{
    Alert.show("Debugger!");
}
else
{
    Alert.show("Not the debugger.");
}
```

... should be what you're looking for.  (If so, my apologies! Post back and I'll adjust accordingly.)

Comment: Technically: (Capabilities.playerType == "Desktop" && Capabilities.isDebugger)

Comment: I have a question, if they just happen to have the debugger version of flash player installed, will that make this inaccurate, or will that not matter? Thanks!!

Comment: It won't matter; AIR has its own runtime.  (I have the debug player installed myself, and verified this example worked before posting it just to be sure.)

Comment: Capabilities.playerType will only return "Desktop" while running in AIR/ADL.

Comment: Just to chime in here, although people will probably already realise it: if you're working on a HTML/JS AIR project, this will work in JS too. Just use: `if(air.Capabilities.playerType == "Desktop" && air.Capabilities.isDebugger)`